# Is the Jacobian of curve self-dual?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Given $C$ an algebraic curve, its Jacobian is isomorphic to its Albanese variety by Abel-Jacobi Theorem. But generally Jacobian and Albanese varieties are dual abelian varieties, does this imply that the Jacobian of a curve is self-dual? Is there a characterization for self-dual abelian varieties?

Comment: A polarization is (in one of its equivalent formulations) an isogeny between an abelian variety and its dual. A principally polarized abelian variety is isomorphic to its dual. Jacobians are principally polarized by the theta divisor.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch So an abelian variety is isomorphic to its dual if and only if it is principally polarized?

Comment: Yes, although it's probably better to say principally polarizable, since the same abelian variety may have different polarizations.

Comment: @Felipe: The definition of a polarization involves a positivity condition (it should correspond to an ample divisor class). So, a principally polarized abelian variety is isomorphic to its dual, but I doubt that the converse is true.